# Xamarin Social component fails to retrieve Twitter json stream

Tags: json, xamarin, twitter, twitter-oauth, xamarin.social

I'm using the following to read Twitter json. It works with one uri and not another.  The uri's work with the Twitter API console but not Xamarin.Social.   I have read and write permissions on the Twitter app so I can't see where I'm going wrong.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json   <-- works
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=AUserName   <-- fails (see error below)


request.GetResponseAsync ().ContinueWith (response => {

            if (response.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (response.Exception.Flatten ()); 
            }

            var json = response.Result.GetResponseText ();


System.AggregateException: One or more errors occured ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x0030c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1606 
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00141] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1423 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --> (Inner exception 0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x0030c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1606 
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00141] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1423
```

[quick google search gave this but not sure if its relevant: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/15206]

```
// UPDATE ***********
```

Does this extra infor help or you need more details?  If so then what details are required?

```
public Account Account
    {
        get
        {
            var task = Service.GetAccountsAsync ()
                .ContinueWith (accounts => 
            {
                return accounts.Result.ToList ().FirstOrDefault ();
            });

            return task.Result;
        }
        set
        {
            AccountStore.Create ().Save (value, SocialPlatform.ToString ());
        }
    }


// later on
// when endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json" <-- works, json returned
// when endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=XXXX" <-- IsFaulted with above error, 

var request = Service.CreateRequest ("GET", endpoint, Account);

        request.GetResponseAsync ().ContinueWith (response => {

            if (response.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (response.Exception.Flatten ());
                return;
            }

            var json = response.Result.GetResponseText ();
            Console.WriteLine (json);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not authorised when you make this call.

From Xamarin.Social documentation.

> Xamarin.Social uses the Xamarin.Auth library to fetch and store
>   Account objects.
>
> Each service exposes a GetAuthenticateUI method that returns a
>   Xamarin.Auth.Authenticator object that you can use to authenticate the
>   user. Doing so will automatically store the authenticated account so
>   that it can be used later.

The reason why it works in Twitter API console is that you have authorised there prior to making a call.

If you are already authorising in your app then please post the code you use to authorise.

Comment: I've added some more code but it's successful on call to one url but not the other...strange?